# Format section's title with \renewcommand

Tags: macros, sectioning, formatting

I have tried to make my sections appear as "Section I : My section's title" or "Section I My section's title" with the `\renewcommand\thesection...` command but in the table of contents the word "Section" is not appearing at the right place. It looks like this:

[image]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\title{my title}
\renewcommand\thesection{Section \ \Roman {section}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\section{my section}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it only in the table of contents you can use the `tocloft` package. If you want to have the word "Section" also in the text you can use the `titlesec` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{Section }
\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{6em}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{Section \thesection\quad}

\title{my title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\pagebreak
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{my section}
\subsection{my section}
\subsection{my section}
\section{another section}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{my section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: \section* gets broken this way, and gives Section 0 blah blah blah